# Android: Pattern.UNICODE_CASE not matching diacritics

Tags: android, regex, pattern-matching, diacritics

I have a regex for names that I wish to match diacritics. Here is a logging snippet from my code starting with test.java:191:

```
Util.Log("text = " + text);
Util.Log("regex = " + regex);
Util.Log("regexorig = " + regexorig);
Util.Log("Matches static: " + Pattern.matches(text,  regex));
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(regex);
Util.Log("Matches p1: " + p1.matcher(text).matches());
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(regexorig, Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Util.Log("Matches p2: " + p2.matcher(text).matches());
Util.Log("String matches: " + text.matches(regex));
```

Here's the output when I use input "ü":

```
LOG: (test.java:191):text = ü
LOG: (test.java:192):regex = (?iu)[A-Z][A-Z0-9 \-.',]*
LOG: (test.java:193):regexorig = [A-Z][A-Z0-9 \-.',]*
LOG: (test.java:194):Matches static: false
LOG: (test.java:196):Matches p1: false
LOG: (test.java:198):Matches p2: false
LOG: (test.java:199):String matches: false
```

I can't seem to get a diacritic-insensitive regex match to work. Is this an Android bug or am I missing something? According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE), UNICODE_CASE is always on for Android case-insensitive strings, so I shouldn't even need it (really not sure why that's the case, but that's a matter for a different discussion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A-Z` still matches only ASCII letters.

Use the Unicode property `\p{L}` (any Unicode letter character) instead. This way, you don't even need the `i` or `u` modifier. Like:

```
\p{L}[\p{L}0-9 \-.',]*
```

There could be one more problem, though. In Unicode, characters with diacritics can also be represented by multiple characters. For instance `á` could be a single Unicode character ([U+00E1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e1/index.htm)), or it could be a `a` ([U+0061](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/61/index.htm)) followed by a combining mark `´` ([U+0301](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm)). `\p{L}` matches only stand-alone characters but not those combining marks. Hence, to catch these cases as well, you might want to insert the Unicode property of combining marks into the repetition as well:

```
\p{L}[\p{L}\p{M}0-9 \-.',]*
```

[Working demo.](http://fiddle.re/tkcaa)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. It appears to differ from iOS in this regard.

Comment: @Oded I just noticed there might be another catch to the problem (and edited the answer)